# How to retrieve nested data structure from Firebase Realtime Database on Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve submittedRequests from database .

[image: My database structure]

```
    userRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {

        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
        }

        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            if(snapshot!!.exists()){
                val children=snapshot!!.children
                for(item in children) {
                    val retrieveUser= item.getValue(User::class.java) //it crashes here
                    if (retrieveUser != null) {
                        userData.add(retrieveUser)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

User Class

`class User(val userId:String="", val name:String="", val surname:String="", val profileImageUrl: String="",val submittedRequests:String="", val pickedUpRequests:String="")`

Error Message is :
`com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String`

How can I retrieve submittedRequests from database properly?

Comment: How is `userRef` declared and initialized?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen `userRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users")`

Comment: There's an edit link right under your question. Please click that and add the information to your question itself.

Answer (score 1):

You're declared `submittedRequests:String=""` in your `User` class. Looking at your JSON the `submittedRequests` is not a simple string, but rather a nested object, or a map.

This should work better

```
submittedRequests:Map<String, Any>=hashMapOf<String, Any>()
```